# Why would the validation 'if not set(sys.argv)' be needed?

Tags: python, sys

I'm trying to understand the first part of the next validation. Can I safely assume that the expression 'if not set(sys.argv)' is always False? Code is from the [Ironic Project](https://github.com/openstack/ironic/blob/master/ironic/cmd/dbsync.py#L99).

```
if not set(sys.argv) & valid_commands:
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), if the command is run with '-c' option, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. Which is still a non-empty set. Example:

```
python -c '
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
if not set(sys.argv):
    print("empty")
else:
    print("non-empty")
'
```

Comment: No, you cannot safely assume that the expression `if not set(sys.argv)` is always false. Your program may have previously cleared `sys.argv`.

Comment: `sys.argv` may also be empty if you call your script using the Python C API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading it wrong. Python's `not` has very low precedence, below that of `&` (which isn't logical AND).

```
if not set(sys.argv) & valid_commands:
```

should be read as

```
if not (set(sys.argv) & valid_commands):
```

which is testing whether `sys.argv` contains any elements of the set `valid_commands`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "first part" here. The

```
if not set(sys.argv) & valid_commands:
```

is equivalent to

```
if not (set(sys.argv) & valid_commands):
```